# How to write a graphql query with json so that the parameter is specified?

Tags: json, graphql

Doesn't work:

```
{
    "query": "mutation{addTodo(title: "hello"){title}}"
}
```

Works but the title is "":

```
{
    "query": "mutation{addTodo{title}}"
}
```

In graphql syntax (worked but I need to use json):

```
mutation{
    addTodo(title:"homework"){
        title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "query": "mutation{addTodo(title: \"hello\"){title}}"
}
```